# Connect multiple hashtags from one line with each other

Tags: r, networking, twitter, hashtag

I've got a list with over 50.000 lines of Tweets. Now I've already exported the hashtags from that list but now I'm stuck with several thousand lines of hashtags which look like this

> hashtag1;hashtag2;hashtag3;hashtag4

Since I want to do a co-hashtag-analysis I'm looking for a way to connect these multiple hashtags with each other without having to manually transform these lines into undirected edges. Example:

> hashtag1;hashtag2
>   hashtag1;hashtag3
>   hashtag1;hashtag4
>   hashtag2;hashtag3
>   hashtag2;hashtag4
>   hashtag3;hashtag4

So, do you have an idea on how to accomplish this task (e.g. via R)? I'm an R-noob and even less "well versed" with other languages but I'm eager to learn.

```html
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L), .Label = c("profitkapital", "resupply", 
"robotik", "rudidutschke", "russland", "sanktionen", "sanktionieren", 
"schiller", "siegertyp", "snowden", "sockeleinkommen", "solidarity", 
"sozialismus", "sozialphilosoph"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 17L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 18L, 18L, 1L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("alltag", 
"arbeit", "bbq", "bge", "blockupy", "deutschland", "digitalisierung", 
"griechenland", "grundeinkommen", "hartziv", "kenfm", "kirche", 
"kopf", "kraft", "marx", "negt", "piraten", "sanktion"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 4L, 14L, 14L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 15L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("", "abitur", "bbqrub", "bge", 
    "brd", "brecht", "deutschen", "fsa", "grundeinkommen", "hartziv", 
    "linkezukunft", "ows", "vatikan", "widerspruch", "würde"
    ), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 
    3L, 3L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "bank", 
    "bge", "eilantrag", "haarp", "job", "jobcentern", "merkel", 
    "pastor", "probleme", "super", "unibrennt"), class = "factor"), 
    V5 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 
    10L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "bge", "bgenation", "fliegen", "geld", 
    "hartziv", "hitler", "sg", "ttip", "vorbild"), class = "factor"), 
    V6 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "altersarmut", "antifa", "bge", "deeznuts", 
    "holocaust", "klatsch", "sex"), class = "factor"), V7 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "bge", 
    "cia", "hartz", "spanishrevolution", "wahre"), class = "factor"), 
    V8 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "cityoflondon", "grund", "peace"), class = "factor"), 
    V9 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "bge", "occupy", "rothschild"), class = "factor"), 
    V10 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "ard", "gezi"), class = "factor"), V11 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "refugeeswelcome", 
    "zdf"), class = "factor"), V12 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "nolegida", 
    "wdr"), class = "factor"), V13 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "nopegida", 
    "swr"), class = "factor"), V14 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "nocastor", 
    "zukunft"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", 
"V14"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -41L))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the package `combinat` with `combn` wich will generate the couple of permutations

```
library(combinat)
combn(c("hashtag1", "hashtag2", "hashtag3", "hashtag4"), 2)
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]      
[1,] "hashtag1" "hashtag1" "hashtag1" "hashtag2" "hashtag2" "hashtag3"
[2,] "hashtag2" "hashtag3" "hashtag4" "hashtag3" "hashtag4" "hashtag4"
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply! :) I tried your suggestion and feel like this is the correct way to proceed (somehow). however, if applied to my data file I get one table with one column and all the contents are "NA". I then tried to fool around with the ", 2)" and replaced it with "min" or "fun" but those didn't work since hashtags are not numeric. 
do you have any further suggestions? :)

Comment: can you edit your post and `dput` your data or at least a part of them?

Comment: yes that's it, but I do not see the hashtags in your data ? So I am not sure what you exactly do with your data ?

Comment: oh, the words are hashtags being used on twitter, I just deleted the hashtag-signs :) and what I want to do is a co-hashtag-analysis which is a network analysis for hashtags (e.g. https://wiki.digitalmethods.net/Dmi/CoWordLifeline)

Comment: ok, assuming the data are `df` then you try this `hashtag = unlist(apply(df, 1, unique)); hashtag2 <- unique(hashtag[hashtag != ""]); combn(hashtag2)`, if it  is what you are looking for.

Comment: mh, didn't get it to work :/ thanks for your input though!
what worked was this, however:

`ndf<-data.frame()`  
`for(i in row.names(dba)){`  
`vals <- dba[i,]`  
`ndf<- rbind(ndf,as.data.frame(t(combn(vals[vals!=""], 2))))`  
`print(i)`  
`}`